# What is the difference between Ntxxx and ZWxxx?

Tags: windows, api, kernel-module

I tried to find the usage of NtqueryDirectoryFile() function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I refered the above link for this. But, They mentioned about Zwxxx (). I couldn't understand Ntxx and ZWxxx. Can anyone explain about this.

Comment: In page you linked there is a link to a nice explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565438(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You asked two different questions. Try to keep a single specific question per, well, question.

Comment: Everything you wanted to know about the difference between the `Nt` and `Zw` native APIs: http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=257  Executive summary: when called from User Mode applications, there's exactly **no** difference.  When called from kernel mode code, there's a subtle difference in that the `Zw` versions of the APIs set the previous mode to Kernel mode which allows the API to implicitly trust the parameters.  Read the linked article for the gory details.

Comment: @MichaelBurr As per your comment. Functionality of those two Native APIs are  same. Only different is, they will call in different mode. Am I correct.

Comment: The basic functionality of the APIs is the same. The linked article goes into great detail about when, what, how and why for the difference.

Comment: With the edit by the OP to remove the "what is native API", this question is no longer "too broad". There's a very specific (and interesting) answer to what the difference is between `Zw` and `Nt` APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically Zw functions are equivalent of Nt functions except they don't do security checks, so are used inside kernel mode only, to avoid the performance penalty.

You can only call Nt functions from user mode, through ntdll.dll. As Michael pointed out Zw functions are just mnemonics to Nt counterparts in user mode.

@Adriano provided a nice link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565438(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)